# How to change URL on window.open? why this doesn't work?

Tags: javascript

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button2" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>
```

button1 and button2 work fine but why doesn't the code work with this URL?

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="window.open('https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom?hl=es-419','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button><br>
<button id="button2" onclick="window.open('https://www.google.com/','popup','width=700,height=300');"><strong>CONTINUAR</strong></button>
```

Problems with the button2 (does not change the URL)?, Any ideas?

Another example: https://js-sozdcc.stackblitz.io/  (button4 with that URL doesn't work)

Comment: could you share a stackblitz  demo?

Comment: @LALIT KANTA DIBYADARSHAN https://js-sozdcc.stackblitz.io/ Problems with the button4

Comment: share your console Error, please.

Comment: Button 4 is the same as button 2, I can't understand what you mean

Comment: @Kaloyan-Velichkov , No information in the chrome console, button4 now is amazon and doesn't work --> https://js-fr8w72.stackblitz.io/

Comment: @AlizeeTicona it works. Try to refresh your page with Ctrl + F5 (to clear the browser cache). Maybe your browser has cached something

Comment: @KaloyanVelichkov Do it: Click button1, then click button2, then click button3, then click button4, then button4 doesn't change the URL

Comment: @AlizeeTicona why do you expect the button will change the URL? Where you want to change this URL?

Comment: @KaloyanVelichkov I want to install the extension from that URL, then change the URL with another click